# How to format allowence of multiple whitespaces between characters in Regex more compact?

Tags: regex

I came up with this regEx to check if a IBAN is entered correctly into a field which also let's the user enter up to 4 whitespaces between character without causing an error.

```
^\s?\s?\s?\s?N\s?\s?\s?\s?\s?O\s?\s?\s?\s?([0-9a-zA-Z]\s?\s?\s?\s?){13}$
```

It works perfectly, but I want to get rid of the "\s?\s?\s?\s?" and format it more compact, I've tried  `[\s?]{4}` but that doesn't work.

What's the correct way to shorten this up?

The system I work with doesn't allow me to use any Javascript, I can only put pure regEx definitions to control entry into the field.

thank you

Comment: Try using `\s{0,4}` shortened `^\s{0,4}N\s{0,4}O\s{0,4}(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]\s{0,4}){13}$` https://regex101.com/r/o89Bzp/1 Note that `\s` could also match a newline

Comment: thank you! what does ?: do if I might ask? :)

Comment: It is a non capturing group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the repeating `\s` parts using a quantifier `{0,4}` to match 0-4 times a whitespace char and add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string to prevent a partial match.

If you don't need that value of the capturing group afterwards, you could make it non capturing `(?:` instead.

```
^\s{0,4}N\s{0,4}O\s{0,4}(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]\s{0,4}){13}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o89Bzp/1)

If you don't want to match a newline, you could use `[^\S\r\n]{0,4}` instead of `\s{0,4}` but that would defeat the purpose of making [the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/yPsdnB/1) smaller.